# How to loop the kernel for covering all pixels from a raster in 5x5 convolution window by using OpenCV?

Tags: python, raster, loop, matplotlib, opencv

Here, I have python code which is helping me in selecting 5 by 5 window from upper left corner of a raster (.tif). I want a process to automate through entire image in 5 by 5 convolution window.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
img = cv2.imread('class.tif')
print(img)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)
print(kernel)
```

How to loop the kernel which will cover all pixels from a raster in 5 by 5 convolution window for getting all pixel values in this convolution window? I don't want to generate another raster. I want location of abnormal values within each window after statistical tests. How is it possible?

Comment: In a deleted former commentary you said: "I don't want to convert raster to an array..." but,  I guess that you want all raster values in a 5x5 window from upper left corner of a raster (.tif)  through entire image in 5x 5 window. I would like to know how will you accomplish this if you don't want to read raster values first.

Comment: Sir, may be I am wrong but using "cv2" module I am able to read an image without converting it into an array . It is reading pixel values only. So I thought if someone has idea to modify it further and serve the purpose.   Further, I don't mind in converting raster to an array but ultimately I need lat-lon of highlighted pixels . If you it is possible even after converting it into an array then I would happy to do that.  @xunilk

Comment: I voted this question for reopening but, why did you choose this **cv2** python module? Did you read its documentation? If you print 'img', you will see that it is a very strange array (yes, an ARRAY!).  If you had read the documentation, you would have seen the need to use flags for a good use of 'imread' method.

Comment: I found out because you chose this amazing python module named **cv2**. I also found out how to loop the kernel for covering all pixels from a raster in 5 by 5 convolution window.

Comment: Thank you for reopening sir. As i said I am not a python pro but I have to use it as I want automation in my thesis work. Yes, I had read the documentation and I found worth trying it. If you have better option suggest any other module to complete this task. Previously I was working with GDAL and nupy for all raster operations should I continue with it? @xunilk

Comment: You're welcome. I've been reading the documentation and **OpenCV** is mainly used for advance vision research (as facial or objects recognition systems) and I not sure if you can recovery pixel location in terms of map units (you said: "I want location of abnormal value within the window...") with 'imread' method (it works with row and column indexes for pixel location). However, you can overcome this generating its respective longitude and latitude rasters for reading them with 'imread'. By using directly GDAL you would also avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you for helping me sir. I will try it using GDAL. @xunilk

Comment: In fact, it's better to use both (gdal and cv2) because you need  "pad" the borders of the input image and cv2 has 'copyMakeBorder' method ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Okay sir I will read the document and try to use both modules. Thank you.@xunilk

Comment: I solve your question with these references: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/ and https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html; in case this question is not reopened.